# Why am I getting an inconvertible type error?

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

If I use this class:

```
public class BooleanTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final Object[] objarray = new Object[2];
        try {
            objarray[0] = "Hello World!";
            objarray[1] = false;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }
        boolean bool = (boolean) objarray[1];
    }
}
```

It works fine and I can assign that `boolean` no problem. Why can I not do the same thing when asking my user for a password?

```
final Object result[] = new Object[2];
try {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0));
            JLabel label = new JLabel();

            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEADING);
            JTextField input = new JTextField();

            input.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox("Pair with this device");
            checkbox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEADING);
            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(input);
            panel.add(checkbox);
            if (wrong) {
                label.setText("Wrong password. Please enter the password from the other device:");
            } else {
                label.setText("Please enter the password from the other device:");
            }
            int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(SendGUI.this, panel, "Enter password", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (response == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                result[0] = input.getText();
                result[1] = (boolean)checkbox.isSelected();
            } else {
                result[0] = null;
                result[1] = false;
            }
        }
    });
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
}
boolean pair = (boolean)result[1]; //inconvertible type, expected boolean found Object
```

As far as I can see I'm doing the same thing in both cases but the first example compiles fine while the second example does not.

Comment: could you post the error you get in the last code?

Comment: @MiguelPrz it was in my code, `inconvertible type, expected boolean found Object`

Comment: @LoganDam: Is this a compile-time error? Are you using the same compiler (with the same options) in both cases?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes. I'm using Netbeans 7.3 as my IDE and compiling both cases with it. In the second example I click run anyway when it warns me about the compiler error, and when it eventually reaches that block of code I get `Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - inconvertible types
  required: boolean
  found:    java.lang.Object`

Comment: @LoganDam: Well start by *not* trying to run code with compile-time errors! Are you certain that your first code compiles without error?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, I'm 100% sure. You can compile it and try for yourself.

Comment: @LoganDam: The thing is, I expect it to compile with Java 6 options but not with Java 7 options... that's why I explicitly said "with the same options".

Comment: @JonSkeet aha, I forgot the one was set to target Java 6. Make an answer about this and I'll accept it. My mistake, thanks so much :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using different compiler options. You must be. Both pieces of code compile under Java 7 rules; neither compiles under Java 6 rules. For example, taking your *first* piece of code (the one that you say compiles for you):

```
c:\Users\Jon\Test>javac -source 1.7 BooleanTest.java

(No console output, i.e. no errors)

c:\Users\Jon\Test>javac -source 1.6 BooleanTest.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
BooleanTest.java:10: error: inconvertible types
        boolean bool = (boolean) objarray[1];
                                         ^
  required: boolean
  found:    Object
1 error
1 warning
```

EDIT: I believe the change is in section 5.5 of the JLS (Casting conversions).

The [Java 7 version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5) includes:

> Casting contexts allow the use of one of:
>
> - ...
> - a narrowing reference conversion (§5.1.6) optionally followed by either an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) or an unchecked conversion (§5.1.9)

The [JLS 3rd edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.5) (Java 5 and 6, basically) includes:

> Casting contexts allow the use of one of:
>
> - ...
> - a narrowing reference conversion (§5.1.6) optionally followed by an unchecked conversion

Note the lack of "an unboxing conversion" there.

Comment: I had forgotten that I was targeting Java 6 in my second example and didn't change that in my first example. Thanks.

Comment: I knew I must've been on the complete wrong track when Jon Skeet tells me I'm wrong :) Of course I figured it out when I actually threw both code snippets in Eclipse but by then Jon had already posted the correct answer.

Comment: @durron597: If it's any consolation, I only knew this because there was a similar question (but not an exact duplicate) a few days ago :)

Comment: @JonSkeet  Wasn't autoboxing introduced in Java 5? Was this a bug in autoboxing that was fixed in 1.7? I'm having a hard time describing what I mean, but does this mean that I can't cast an `Object` to an `int` until 1.7?

Comment: @JuanMendes: Yes, autoboxing was introduced in Java 5 - but the exact nature of autoboxing and unboxing changed in Java 7. Either there was a change in the language specification, or it was a bug in the Java 6 compiler. I wouldn't like to say which, to be honest - but I *suspect* it's a language spec change.

Comment: @JuanMendes: Actually, I think it's a change in section 5.5 of the JLS. I'm putting the difference in my answer·

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
result[1] = (boolean)checkbox.isSelected();
```

To:

```
result[1] = Boolean.valueOf(checkbox.isSelected());
```

Comment: For the downvoters I meant to do Boolean.valueOf instead of `new Boolean`. I just couldn't type fast enough on my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is related with [Autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) in Java 1.6

You put a primitive type into Object array. Java can not mix primitive with Object, therefore it wrap that primitive boolean into Boolean.

So what you are doing can not be represented as:

`boolean result = (boolean) Boolean.TRUE;`

The solutions are:

1. Replace the Object array with boolean array.
2. Use `Boolean.TRUE.equals(result[1])`;
3. Switch to Java 1.7 as John pointed out in his answer.

Comment: This does not explain why my first example works without error.

Comment: @LoganDam It should not. Are yo sure it works? Just try again.

Comment: Well, not everyone has a privilege to work on the latest version of Java.

Comment: @JonSkeet, small changes and we are again on track. Nice catch with that different compilers.

Comment: @JonSkeet Most probably that Java 7 have fix the issue in the compiler/runtime. Who want boxing and primitive type? yurk. More about it: http://gbracha.blogspot.ru/2009/09/systemic-overload.html

Comment: @LoganDam it does explain why your first snippet is working. Because of autoboxing. And your second snippet does not work because of a bug in the compiler/runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the boolean by [Boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html), which it's a class that inhereits from java.lang.Object and you have the Boolean.TRUE and Boolean.FALSE

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 Boolean pair = (Boolean)result[1];
```

Comment: This may fix the problem but my question is not how to fix it and rather why is it a problem in the first place.

Comment: there is same problem in your first example i.e. object to primitive type conversion error